# VHD only 1/2 full reporting as full

Tags: windows-11, vhd

I have a lot of photos on google and wanted to start moving away.  I created a (fixed) VHD under Windows and spent slices of time over several months downloading and organizing these images.  I ran out of room on the VHD.

Create a new (dynamic) 50% larger than before, attached both, started moving the files from A to B.  When 2/3 of the files were moved I hit an out of room error!

Dir on my C:\VHD directory shows:

- VHD A - 100GB
- VHD B - 150GB

Mount and do properties:

- VHD A - 25GB used (as expected)
- VHD B - 75GB used (and reporting full)

For the life of me I cannot figure out what is going on!

Note:  Numbers are not exact but within +/-5%...

Comment: How much *actual* drive space do you have left on wherever these are located? A fixed VHD should already occupy the entire allocated size, but a dynamic will grow as required.

Comment: I currently have 201GB free on the drive where the VHDs live

Comment: Mount the VHD into windows and check disk management to see if the partition is actually spanning the entire vhd space. Chances are that it is not.

Comment: I did - results are in the OP.  When I look on the bare metal drive the suspect VHD reports using 150GB of drive space.  When I mount it and select all the directories in that drive and do right-click, properties, it reports just over 75GB with 1GB free.